# Best way to use the .sample() in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, sample

I have a data frame of 217 columns. Till now I was sampling it by giving a specific number. The sampled data-frame was then used to apply a LinearRegression model to predict a score. The code I was using to achieve this is the following:

```
sample_lr = sample_lr.sample(5,axis=1)
```

sample_lr looks like the following:

```
    SHOCKS_1    SELFCONTROL_3   SOCSEC3     EMPLOY1_3   EMPLOY1_9   FWBscore
0      0             3            -2          0           0           55
1      0             3            66          0           0           51
2      0             3            68          0           0           49
3      0            -1            -1          0           1           49
4      0             3            65          0           0           49
```

```
if "FWBscore" in sample_lr:
    pass
else:
    sample_lr["FWBscore"] = df["FWBscore"]

sample_lr_2 = sample_lr.drop("FWBscore", axis=1)

X = sample_lr.drop('FWBscore', axis= 1)
y = sample_lr.FWBscore
linear_model = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
sample_lr_2 = sample_lr.drop("FWBscore", axis=1)
sample_lr_2['FWBscore_PREDICT'] = linear_model.predict(sample_lr_2)
score = linear_model.score(X, y)
```

What I have to do now is to show, using a plot, how by increasing the sampling number, which the user could change, the score increase. So my idea was to use a for-loop.

```
sample_lr = df.iloc[:500,:]

for i in range(1,5):
    sample_lr = sample_lr.sample(i, axis = 1)
    print(sample_lr)
```

which gives me a problem with the replace=False. I need to keep it false because the sample should have all column unique and if I set as True it will just copy the same column 5 times. What I would like to use by printing is that the first time I have only one column, the second two column and so on.
There is a way to achieve what I want? What I am not considering?

Comment: you can sample as much as you want with `replace=False` as long as you are under your data's full length

Comment: If I sample without giving a number of rows I have the following error "Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False"

Comment: didnt you say you want to increment the number of samples after each iteration?

Comment: Yes. So when it starts it uses just one column to make the prediction of the score, the second time two, and so on and so forth.